# Prevent World reset between each Scenario

Tags: node.js, typescript, cucumberjs

I'm working with Cucumber-js and Typescript.

I would like to create and initialize a driver for my tests. I want this driver to be initialized in an async scope, so that no test begin before it has been setup (which can take up to 10 seconds), and once it is initialized I won't have to do it again for each Scenario.
I tried to store the driver in the a custom World class and initialize it only once within the BeforeAll function, but I can't access `this` in this function :

```
class Context implements World {
  public driver: Driver

  public constructor() {
    this.driver = new Driver()
  }

  public async init_driver() {
    await this.driver.init()
  }
}
```

and

```
BeforeAll( async function() {
  setWorldConstructor(Context)

  await this.init_driver() // error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation
})
```

And even if this worked, the World is reset before each Scenario, so how could I use `this.driver` in my steps without having to setup the driver before each one ?

Answer (score 0):

First statement in this page 'https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/world.md' says, this will be accessible in hooks and world files itself and its scope is limited to these two files only.

Reusing launched driver object:

1) Create a separate class (For ex: ReUse) with a static variable called 'driver'.
2) Create a class called hooks and import above created class here
3) Using Before() function in hooks file, we can handle it in this way:

if(typeof ReUse.driver === 'undefined') {
-- browser launching code and assigning that object to same ReUse.driver varibale.
}

By this way, When first scenario started, ReUse.driver will hold undefined and will go inside the if block. There we launch driver object and assign it to ReUse.driver variable.
When second scenario started, this ReUse.driver will hold driver object and the condition will not be satisfied. Hence, no more driver will be launched..